# Grails integration test not recognising controller save method

Tags: grails, testing

I recently upgraded a project from 2.2 to 2.4.4, and upgraded the integration tests by replacing

```
IntegrationTest extends GroovyTestCase
```

with

```
@TestMixin(IntegrationTestMixin)
```

My controllers have save methods e.g. :

```
class IssueController {

    def save() { 
        ...
        if (!issueService.save(issue)) { 
            render(view: "create", model: [issueInstance: issue]) 
            return 
        } 
    }
```

and the integration test (in test/integration) :

```
@Before 
void setUp() { 
    ic = new IssueController() 
} 

@Test 
void testValidSave() { 

    ic.params.issueNo = "test" 

    ic.save() 
        assert ic.flash.successAlert ==  "Saved issue test" 
        assert ic.response.redirectUrl == '/issue/list' 
    }
```

but my Integrations tests, when calling ic.save() don't call the controller save method (and so fail). If I rename the save() method to say saveIt(), and the call to ic.saveIt(), everything works fine

but I don't want to have to rename all my controller method names.

Comment: Check the allowed methods on action, like `static allowedMethods = [save: "POST", update: "PUT", delete: "DELETE"]`

Comment: That worked, thanks! I had to either remove allowedMethods or change save to "GET", do you know why this is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need to remove `allowedMethods` or no need to change to GET just do in test case

`ic.request.method = "POST"` if allowed method is post.